# Counter in lottery-game

Tags: java, arrays

i wanted to create my first lottery_game. User has to type in 6 numbers, they are saved in array. In another array some random numbers are generated.

Now i want to compare the content. I want to know if my number of the first array i content of the second array. If yes the variable counter gets + 1. Then i want to know the counter.

It works until i wanted to know the counter. Then i get this error:

Please put in 6 numbers
5
8
9
7
4
5
Your numbers are: 5 8 9 7 4 5
The lottery numbers today are: 25 24 18 15 6 27 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Lotto_zwei.main(Lotto_zwei.java:48)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    System.out.println("Please put in 6 numbers"); //Start
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner
    int[] numbers = new int[6]; //Array of numbers
    int counter = 0;
    int[] lottery_numbers = new int[6];
    int randomNum;
    /* Loop_1 */
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) { 
        numbers[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    /* Loop_2*/
    System.out.print("Your numbers are: ");
    for(int y : numbers) {
        System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");


    /* Loop_3 */
    for(int i=0;i<lottery_numbers.length;i++) {
        randomNum= (int) (Math.random() * 50);
        for(int x=0;x<i;x++) {
            if(lottery_numbers[i] == lottery_numbers[x]) {
                randomNum= (int) (Math.random() * 50);
                x--;
            }
        }
        lottery_numbers[i] = randomNum;
    }
    /* Loop_4 */
    System.out.print("The lottery numbers today are: ");
    for(int z : lottery_numbers) {
        System.out.print(z + " ");
    }

    /* Loop_5 */
    for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++) {
        for(int x=0;i<lottery_numbers.length;x++) {
            if(numbers[i]==lottery_numbers[x]) {
                counter = counter +1;
            }
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }

    }
    System.out.println("You got: " + counter + " right ones");
}
```

Comment: i think the array index is out of bounds

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You are trying to access the index 6 of an array that has a max capacity of less than that, probably 5.

Comment: i understand the error message, but i still didnt know what to change, thats why i´m asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
for(int x=0;i<lottery_numbers.length;x++) {
```

to:

```
for(int x=0;x<lottery_numbers.length;x++) {
```

Comment: Thank you, i didn´t see this stupid mistake :)

Comment: You are welcome!